# Convert EPSG:3347 into EPSG:4326; nothing worked

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I tried really hard to change the CRS of my polygons and the file properties say it was changed, yet the dynamic coordinates window on the bottom continues to show initial CRS (EPSG:3347) and when I extract geometry into CSV using MMGIS plugin - I get the nodes with old CRS EPSG:3347 coordinates.

I've tried saving a shapefile with a new CSR, using OTF, I have tried saving the layer as a CSV file with the CRS reset, saving the project, ... nothing worked. Is there some formula like radians to degrees? I don't know Python but need this a lot...

My initial shapefile is [here: census subdivisions, cartographic file](http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/bound-limit-2016-eng.cfm)

Comment: When you save the data to a new shapefile, make sure you're setting the coordinate system in the 'save as' dialogue box, not in the OTF settings... OTF is just for map display, while doing a 'save as' with the CRS set to 4326 will get you what you need.

Comment: what software are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Exactly, DPSSpatial pointed to the solutioin: you just need to make sure you save your shapefile into your EPSG 4326 CRS (see pic below).

> "When you save the data to a new shapefile, make sure you're setting the coordinate system in the 'save as' dialogue box, not in the OTF settings... OTF is just for map display, while doing a 'save as' with the CRS set to 4326 will get you what you need."

The OTF projecton means "on the fly" and is not changing the CRS of any visible layer...it just reprojects all visible layers into a common CRS for visualization.

[image]